# How to convert Direct Current to Alternate Current (DC to AC)?

Tags: current, ac, dc

I want to make a circuit that converts Direct current to Alternate current. Is it possible at home without using any expensive resources. I know I have to use some resources but I want this as simple as one can.

```
DC to AC
```

I know how to convert Alternate to Direct current, but for reverse I don't know how to do this. Someone please help if he can.

I don't know more about electronics. I'm a Software Engineer but I have to work with electronics too.

Comment: This circuit is called an inverter. Before you design one, you need to decide, how what voltage, current, and frequency you want it to operate at.

Comment: Also, before you make an inverter to supply a device that expects mains voltages, you want to be sure you know enough to do it without electrocuting yourself.

Comment: If by this you just mean "Can I make an AC sine wave using DC to power it?" then it's not so hard. One or two BJTs can get there. If you want it to actually drive a load such as a speaker with a dozen watts of power, at least another 5 BJTs and a larger DC power supply rail. If you want it to actually provide AC power capable of driving motors, then you want an inverter and it's a much bigger problem. Given the "simple as one can" comment, I'd say you need to focus merely on producing a reasonable sine wave into a modest (\$1\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$) load. Two BJTs for that.

Answer (score 2):

An inverter can be as simple as a voltage source,   few resistors, a pair of NPN and PNP transistors in a totem pole setup, and a transformer.  You can totally do this as a diy, but a pre built commercial car inverter would work better at a higher efficiency at a lower cost.

Comment: I think the OP needs to be very careful before he/she tries to build one such inverter. A lot of circuits on the Internet shows these transistor-based circuits, which are usually driven by a square wave (IC555, IC4017, etc.). The sharp voltage transitions may cause very high induced voltage in the transformer's secondary coil.